# Searching a string using regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, string, search, substring

I wonder how to retrieve more similar patterns present in a string array no matter the string length and how many such similar patterns existed..

For example:

> Harry James Potter also known as Mr.Potter . Potter is very famous in hagwards. Harry James Potter also called Mr.Potter.

I need to find the contents between Harry James Potter  and Mr.Potter:

The output should be

1. also known as
2. also called

Can any one help me out?

here is my code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class RegexTestHarness {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String regex = "Harry James Potter (.*?) Mr.Potter";

        String strToSearch = "Harry James Potter also known as Mr.Potter. Harry       James Potter is famous as  Mr. Potter";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strToSearch);

        while (matcher.find()) {

            System.out.println("Text is at "+matcher.group()+"::"+matcher.start()+"::     "+matcher.end());
            System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());

            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are sure that Harry James Potter a.k.a is Mr.Potter it can be Mr.Harry or Mr.James ?

Comment: okay.. I think it is not required i just need the patterns between those strings specified Harry James Potter and Mr.Potter , If such names like Mr. Harry or Mr. James are in the text i simply discard them.

Comment: Your regex has `Mr.Potter` within it. The `.` should be escaped (`\.`) to match specifically "." rather than any character.

Comment: What does your code produce currently?

Comment: Even though without specifying any \ before  "." the programs gives me output like this   the groupcount() produces 1 as output and the group retrieved is "also known as" but i need both outputs "also known as" and "is famous as"

Answer (score 0):

This regex will pick up anything contained between "Harry James Potter" and "Mr.Potter":

```
Harry James Potter (.*?) Mr\.Potter
```

Tested [here](http://fiddle.re/ywxb)

Depending on your implementation of Regex, you may need to retrieve result group 1.

Comment: Yes , it is right but i need all such groups existed , i already tried using that regular expression but it retrieves me entire text matching from Harry James Potter to end of the string

Comment: Make sure you use `(.*?)`, not just `(.*)`.

Comment: What version of regex are you using? The `()` should specify the group to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you escape the period in Mr.Potter when writing your regex string.  Also your strToSearch had random spaces in it which would make your regex not find what you are after.  This code produces the example that you provided.

```
try {
        String regex = "Harry James Potter (.*?) Mr\\.Potter";
        String strToSearch = "Harry James Potter also known as Mr.Potter. Potter is very famous in hagwards. Harry James Potter also called Mr.Potter.";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strToSearch);
        int start = 0;
        int count = 1;
        while (matcher.find(start)) {
            System.out.println(count + ". " + matcher.group(1));
            start = matcher.end();
            count++;
        }

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nealvs.. Really it's working. You have raised one point un-necessary spaces but in the text stream i got,there are lots of un necessary spaces(That program is not shown) are present then what should i do to make sure that all the existed patterns are retrieved??

Answer (score -1):

```
    String s = "Harry James Potter also known as Mr.Potter . Potter is very famous in hagwards. Harry James Potter also called Mr.Potter.";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Harry James Potter )(.*?)(?= Mr.Potter)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {            
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

output :

```
also known as
also called
```